# How to set the state in Redux from a component passing payload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I can't set the state with mapDispatchToProps and pass the payload

Imports:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './HoursWatched.mod ule.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionType from '../../../store/actions';
```

This is how I try to trigger the action:

```
   componentDidMount() {
        this.getHoursWatched()
    }

    getHoursWatched() {
        axios.get(API_URL, header)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                this.props.hoursWatched(res)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log("Error", err)
            })
    }
```

The mapDiscpatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      hoursWatched : (res) => dispatch({ type: actionType.HOURS_WATCHED, payload: res })
    }
  }
```

Exports:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HoursWatched);
```

In the reducer:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action, payload) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.HOURS_WATCHED:
            const newHoursWatched = {};
                console.log(payload) //This is undefined
            return {
                ...state,
                hoursWatched: newHoursWatched
            };
```

Why I can't pass the payload? It says it's undefined

Comment: Just check "Line 38:80" and make sure you spelled the name correctly. Because it looks like you don't `hourswatched` vs `hoursWatched`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to refer to a wrong argument in the reducer. In order to access the payload that you are passing from the API response you need to use `action.payload` in the reducer instead of `payload`.